# Why is TouchRipple.js different in material-ui/core v4.7.0 git tag compared to @material-ui/core 4.7.0 npm package?

Tags: material-ui

When using @material-ui/core version 4.7.0 from npm there's a bug (possibly same root cause as https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12362) in:

`node_modules/@material-ui/core/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js`

which has been fixed in the repository on github:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/commit/1f06b38f9a50a10c5f70f709ad8d6ab14667d88b#diff-783df2b03ee5576330196d85b723e152R188

The thing I don't understand is that this fix is included in the git tag v4.7.0:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/2b04ee905695540bde87653908ece5c4d57546c9/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js#L182

but why isn't it then included in the 4.7.0 version npm package?

Comment: The differences between the npm version vs. GitHub are just babel transformations. The code at line 182 that you linked to is present in the npm version at line 221.

Comment: Thank you Ryan that's of course it. The root cause I'm looking for is unrelated to this. :)